# Outlook VSTO disable prompt asking to save message after subject changes

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I wrote a VSTO ribbon button to mass change subjects on existing MailItem. However, it is not working 100% of the time. I am suspecting that the prompt asking me to save email after subject change is preventing the subject change.

How to suppress the dialog programmatically so that I can mass change subjects, then un-suppress the dialog thereafter.

```
public void EditSubject()
{
    var explorer = _OutlookApplication.ActiveExplorer();
    var selection = explorer.Selection;
    List<MailItem> mailItems = new List<MailItem>();
    foreach(var item in selection)
    {
        var mailitem = item as MailItem;
        if(mailitem != null) mailItems.Add(mailitem);
    }

    if(mailItems.Count > 0)
    {
        using (var form = new FormEditSubject())
        {
            form.Subject = mailItems[0].Subject;

            if (form.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // changing subject works, but does not work 100% of the time.
                // Save prompt dialog shows when closing outlook.
                mailItems.ForEach(item => item.Subject = form.Subject);
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} MailItems subject edited to: {1}", mailItems.Count, form.Subject));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant snippets of your code. When exactly is the prompt shown?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko code snippet added. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never call `MailItem.Save()` after modifying the Subject property